# Collection wrapping a array is read-only. Possible to make it writeable without casting?

Tags: c#

I have a `Collection<T>` property that wraps a array like

```
T[] array;

public Collection<T> Items
{
     get { return new Collection<T>(array); }
}
```

When I attempt to assign to the collection via:

```
T variable;
Items[i] = variable;
```

I get a `NotSupportedException` because the colleciton's `IsReadOnly` property is `true`.  Turns out that this is a design choice by [Microsoft](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/91144/converting-an-array-to-a-collection-creates-a-read-only-collection).  Does anyone know a workaround that does NOT involve enumeration?  It could be done if the underlying data is not an array but I enjoy the performance gains because the data is fixed length.

Comment: Why not just type your property as `IList<T>` and return the array directly instead?  It's not clear what you're gaining by wrapping the array in a `Collection<T>`... could you expand on the requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is no way around this.  Arrays implementation of `Collection<T>` fits the read only model which means it will throw on attempted writes.

If you need to have a mutable collection then I would suggest using a `List<T>` under the hood instead of an array.  You can force it to have the same initial size as well.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just access the array directly then? If you're already expecting it to be fixed length, wrapping it in a Collection doesn't really get you any added benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to "cheat", you could reflection to the the internal "items" field of the Collection.  According to Reflector that's what it's called.  Don't recommend this approach though.